# Data in List<String> to be assigned to multiselect picklist in apex

Tags: apex, multi-select

In my apex code, i have a list of string stored in a LIST. I want to insert record and assign the List to a multiselect picklist field.
Please Suggest.

```
String vals;
List<sObject> records = new List<sObject>([Select PicklistField__c from Object]);
for(sObject s : records ){
    vals = String.join(s.PicklistField__c , ';');
}
```

Gives me error

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void join(String,
>   String) from the type String

Comment: @adrian-larson I have Answered for updated question which is present now.  As sfdcfox was answered for previous question before updating this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just join the values with a semi-colon:

```
record.MultiSelectField__c = String.join(selectedValues,';');
```

Alternatively, you might consider binding the multi-select list directly to the field:

```
<apex:selectList multiple="true" value="{!record.MultiSelectField__c}">
   <apex:selectOptions value="{!availableOptions}" />
</apex:selectList>
```

Comment: @sfdfox No need to create a List of select option and assigning it ? directly will work ?

Comment: @NITHESHK Yes, presuming I've read the question correctly, it's just a normal String value, with the values separated by semi-colons, as demonstrated in the code I provided. You only need a list of SelectOption if you're going to use apex:selectOptions to render a list on the screen.